# How to know which icon is clicked in UIActivityViewController before activityController setCompletionHandleris called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, twitter, uiactivityviewcontroller

How to know which icon is clicked in `UIActivityViewController` before  `activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)`  is  called  ?

I want to share different text for sharing with twitter and facebook.

```
-(IBAction)btnSharePressedFromOffersDetail:(id)sender
{
NSString *posturl= @"facebook or twitter";
UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *printData = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc]init];
NSArray *Itemsarray=@[posturl,printData];
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:Itemsarray applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityController
                   animated:YES completion:nil];
[activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)
{
     NSLog(@"Activity = %@",activityType);
     NSLog(@"Completed Status = %d",completed);  
     if (completed)
     {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                         message:@"Thanks for sharing!"
                                                        delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert show];
     }
     else
     {       
     }
 }];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to use a different text for Twitter or Facebook, it's the responsability of your shared Model who implement the UIActivityItemSource protocol.

```
- (id) activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
    if([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]) return @"Facebook text";
    else if([activityType UIActivityTypePostToTwitter]) return @"Twitter text";
    else return @"Default text";
}
```

Comment: i wrote this method but not called.

Comment: Do you create your ActivityViewController like this ?

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[YOUR_MODEL] applicationActivities:nil];

Comment: You need to create an object who implement the UIActivityItemSource protocol.

The activityViewController:itemForActivityType had to be implemented in this object.

It's this object you need to share, not the posturl string.

Comment: @EricD this method is not called my code is=> UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil]; so how can i call this method and check button icon state ?

Answer (score 1):

You can go with link given below, there is tutorial which might helps you.

https://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/objective-c-custom-uiactivityviewcontroller-icons-and-text/

and http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/